# Gmap does not work on iPhone

Tags: google-maps

I am using the Gmap module to display a map on the page; however, it works on the PC, but not on the iPhone.
I checked the iPhone debug console, and got the following error:

> Drupal.gmap [undefined] is not an object

Could anyone please suggest me the way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem; it was caused by the JavaScript file. This is what I have tried:

1. Open the file of "/sites/all/modules/gmap/gmap.module"
2. Find the function "_gmap_doheader()"
3. Find the line begin with "drupal_set_html_head('

   Move it to the second line of _gmap_doheader(), so it may look like:

   ```
   function _gmap_doheader() {    
     drupal_set_html_head('<script src=xxx    
     static $gmap_initialized = FALSE;
     // …
   }
   ```

   Upload the file to /sites/all/modules/gmap/

   Flush all caches

Answer (score 2):

So your solution hacks the module code. Do the community a favour and submit your change to the issue cue for the module so that everyone can share in your success or even better roll a patch for the authour to apply to the module code.